# PHP ldap_bind() authentication - error Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials?

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to authenticate a user with LDAP using PHP.  I have the DN for the user which I have checked to be correct.  I also have a password.  This is the correct password for the user when they authenticate with `SamAccountName`.

I am hoping this is the password to use when authenticating with the DN.  There isn't a Distinguished Name specific password for LDAP is there?   The following is my code to authenticate using PHP's `ldap_bind()` function.  Am I doing this correct?

```
$ldaphost="ldap://somehost.com:3268";
$dn = "cn=LastName\, FirstName Dept/Country/ext,OU=Accounts,OU=Location,ou=Division,";
$basedn="dc=abc,dc=enterprise";

if (!($connect = ldap_connect($ldaphost))) {    
  die ("Could not connect to LDAP server"); 
} 

$ldapbind = ldap_bind($connect, "$dn" . "$basedn", $password);

if ($ldapbind) {
   echo "LDAP bind successful...";
} else {
   echo "LDAP bind failed...";
}
```

The result I get from the above code is :

> Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server:
>   Invalid credentials LDAP bind failed...

From the line where `ldap_bind()` call is made:

```
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($connect, "$dn" . "$basedn", $password);
```

Invalid credentials makes me believe there is something wrong potentially with the DN or password.  I have triple checked the DN and there is not an error there as far as I can see.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you are connecting to a Microsoft Domain, you can try the domain syntax for the credentials then. For User015 in DOMAIN - DOMAIN\user015

Comment: Bingo!! That works! So the userid you use in ldap_bind() depends on the type of domain of the ldap server?  Or can the admin of the server change it?  So on some ldap domains you use the DN, on others you use DOMAIN\user.  And others potentially userid is an email address?

Comment: @user840930 The DOMAIN\user is only allowed on Microsoft Domain Controllers, LDAP default is to require (I may be wrong here) the full DN wich I find amusing as this is only available in LDAP.

Comment: @Stephan B can you please tell me where we can change this DOMAIN\user? Can you please assist me?

Comment: @ErSharadSoni Please post a new question and clarify what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 4):

When ever dealing with ldap I always find [jxplorer](http://jxplorer.org/) useful